# Jquery Drag: Having a second image following your mouse while dragging first image

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, mousemove

I am messing around with JQuery UI's draggable feature and its working great, but I am stumped in one particular task.

I have two images. What I want to happen is that when I start dragging image1, image2 will automatically attain my mouse's X and Y position and follow the mouse along as im dragging image 1, and ONLY when Im dragging Image1. The moment I let go of dragging image1, image2 should also stop in the place its at (which should be in the same position as image1).

Is there a simple way to do this? It doesnt have to use JQuery or JQuery UI if it doesnt have to.

http://jsfiddle.net/Z94V8/1/

```
<div id="div1"></div>
<div id="div2"></div>

 $(function() {
$( "#div1" ).draggable();
});

#div1 {
    width:25px;
    height:25px;
    background-color:red;
}

#div2 {
     width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Comment: is there jsFiddle to examine?

Comment: Posted link, its pretty basic.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[**Here is working jsFiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/Z94V8/9/)

```
$(window).mousemove(function() {
    var curLeft = parseInt($('#div1').css('left'));
    var curTop = parseInt($('#div1').css('top'));
    console.log(curLeft+'-'+curTop);

    $('#div2').css({'left': curLeft +'px','top': curTop +'px'})
});
```